# How do I get the location of a P.O. Box?

Tags: azure-maps

I am using Azure Maps and when I give it a P.O. Box, it tells me it cannot provide a longitude & latitude for it. I need this for find stuff within a rough distance and so I'd prefer the lat/long of the actual post office, but anything in the area would work.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In which country's postal-system are you looking to geolocate their PO Boxes? It's entirely possible that the information is non-public or changes too frequently, or are routed internally, which may make this impossible.

Comment: @Dai In the U.S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

US PO Boxes are not generally geocodable. At best, if you have the address the PO Box is located at, you can put that address in. This is not an Azure Maps specific limitation but a general limitation. There are a lot of funky things that go on with PO Boxes (they can be moved to other addresses).

Comment: Definitely not the answer I was hoping for. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I ran into many of these issues with PO Boxes about a decade ago. Unfortunately there hasn't been much change in how the US Postal services treats these.

Answer (score 0):

> I need this to find stuff within a rough distance and so I'd prefer the lat/long of the actual post office

You can use the below python code to get the latitude and longitude of the post office in the USA.

**Code:**

```
from azure.maps.search import MapsSearchClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

# Set the address
address = "United States Postal Service"
subscription_key = "Your azure map subscription-key "
search_api =MapsSearchClient(credential=AzureKeyCredential(subscription_key))
response = search_api.search_address(query=address)
if len(response.results) > 0:
    print(f"Coordinate: {response.results[0].position.lat},{response.results[0].position.lon}")
```

**Output:**

```
Coordinate: 43.62057,-70.32654
```

[image]

**Map:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to create Azure Maps applications using the Python REST SDK (preview) - Azure Maps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-dev-guide-py-sdk)

Comment: Unless I'm not seeing something that is getting you the address of a random post office. Not a specific post office. Do you have the city/state there somewhere and I missed it?

Comment: @David Thielen, In your Query you have asked for the Long/Lat of a location, in my repro the same has been shown. However, just for an example I have given a specific PO office to validate, you can try the same code with any random Post office Address and you will get your desired Longitude and Latitude.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I read your example the address you give is "United States Postal Service" which could be anywhere. I need it for "P.O. Box 123, Denver, CO" to get the specific post office that PO box is at. ???

Comment: Yes, you can use the same address in my code to get the longitude and latitude.

Comment: I've tried that - it doesn't work. Please try yourself with a valid POB and you'll see.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you it shows the street of the address does not have a P O box. I tried with the same [code](https://i.imgur.com/jCbOCkH.png) and in [Map](https://i.imgur.com/hOum6dZ.png) yeah I think it has limitations in maps.